# How to execute eval() code and get all the params

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, eval

## The Problem

I'm allowing the user to write some code in text code editor something like this eg:

```
var Player = function(){ 

    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 32;
    this.height = 64;

}

Player.prototype.run = function(){
    this.x++;
}
```

### The Question

I want to execute this code (any javascript) using `eval()` ? Store it in a variable or something, so then I can loop through it and create html entities. Some example **PSEUDO CODE**:

```
loop through varables // loop through the entities that the user created.
    print varable_name // print the name of varable ("Player")
    print varable.width  // Print the varable entitiy ("32");
```

#### Some example code :

```
for (var name in this) {
    variables[name] = name;
    variables[name]=this[name]
}

function maskedEval(scr){
    var mask = {};
    for (p in this)
        mask[p] = undefined;

    // execute script in private context
    (new Function( "with(this) { " + scr + "}")).call(mask);
}
```

Is there anyway to dynamically to do this? Or is there a better way to do this? I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks ;)

Comment: So you'd like to eval whatever the user types in? Sounds like a great idea.

Comment: @adeneo What could go wrong?!

Comment: @adeneo The user can type code in the console. It's the same thing. I can't think of anything that would go wrong. The code is not executed in other user browsers, it's your script.

Comment: When you eval the code, it's going to be executed on the global scope, meaning if they create a variable called `Application` and you already have one named `Application`, it will overwrite your variable. Because of this, it would be better if you instead executed the code inside of a sandbox, such as an iframe so that it won't interfere with your code, and your code won't interfere with the user's code. For example, sending the code to the server, then having the server produce a page with the code to be displayed in the iframe.

Comment: You need to narrow the scope of your problem. Yes, somebody can modify the game to fit his or her needs, but a sandbox'ed eval doesn't make sense unless you're trying to implement a console or do scripting.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure that's accurate, actually. It's certainly safer to sandbox user-submitted code with an iframe on another domain; but in what little testing I've done, you actually *can* sandbox `eval()` if you really strip the scope down.

Comment: I should have also mentioned, I honestly don't know what the question is here. Better way to do what exactly? Execute user code? Better in what way?

Comment: @KevinB I don't think `eval` executes in the global scope - it executes in the local scope. `Function` and `setTimeout` execute in the global scope though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice way to handle the code by placing it into a temporary hashed JavaScript file;

Demo: http://so.ghostsofthesun.com/user_965921/

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .floatClear {
            clear: both;
        }

        #userScript, #result {
            float: left;
            font-family: monospace;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px 15px;
            width: 500px;
            min-height: 300px;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #eee;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 5px solid orange;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
            outline: none;
        }

        #result {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #submitCode {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submitCode').click(function() {
                var input = {'code' : JSON.stringify($('#userScript').val().trim())};

                $.post('process_code.php', input, function(data) {
                    $('#result').html('YES');
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    js_file_path = data.js_file_path;
                    $('script[data^=tmp_js]').remove();
                    $('head').append('<script data="tmp_js" src="' + js_file_path + '"><\/script>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="userScript">var test = 21; console.log(test);</textarea>
    <div id="result">Result will be here</div>
    <div class="floatClear"></div>
    <button id="submitCode">Execute code!</button> (The left panel is editable)
</body>
</html>
```

**process_code.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
        $code = json_decode($_POST['code']);

        // Create new JS file
        $js_file = 'tmp_'.md5(microtime()).'.js';
        $handle = fopen($js_file, 'w') or die('can\'t open file');
        fwrite($handle, $code);
        fclose($handle);

        $full_path = 'http://localhost:8888/'.$js_file;

        echo json_encode(array('js_file_path' => $full_path));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Code wasn\'t recieved correctly.'));
    }

    // Do someting to remove the created JS-file after a certain time (cache/buffer empty)
?>
```

.. and replace;

```
$full_path = 'http://so.ghostsofthesun.com/user_965921/'.$js_file;
```

.. with your host path (or detect it automatically with the `$_` super-globals.

Of course you can just re-route the code into the script-tag directly, but as I had this on hand I thought I would just share the full shebang instantly :)

Modern browsers will notice the added script tags and will execute it instantly. IE might not play well with this; you might want to test it on different platforms. Otherwise you could search on the internet for methods to invoke the JavaScript after the script is embedded live.

Other example to input into the left field;

```
$('#result').css({
    'font-size' : '60px',
    'color' : 'blue',
    'background' : '#aaa'
});
```

Extra note;

You might want to use `$.getScript()` (as I just found out) instead of re-binding the dynamic script-tag;

```
$.post('process_code.php', input, function(data) {
    $('#result').html('YES');
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    js_file_path = data.js_file_path;
    $.getScript(js_file_path);
    //$('script[data^=tmp_js]').remove();
    //$('head').append('<script data="tmp_js" src="' + js_file_path + '"><\/script>');
});
```